# Console Output Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, console

Every single time I run my test case, some of the put is spaced out while others are connected, why is that and what's the fix? Here's a sample code and a picture of console output [Console output results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7bxl.png)`

```
        if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Create Report"))
        {

            System.out.println("   Test Case 2a Report Page Create Report Field Passed");
        }
        else{

            System.out.println("   Test Case 2a Report Page Create Report Field Failed");
        }
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Quick Reports
    // Ensure the dates are visible

        if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Quick Reports"))
        {

            System.out.println("   Test Case 2b Report Page Quick Reports Field Passed");
        }
        else{

            System.out.println("   Test Case 2b Report Page Quick Reports Field Failed");
        }
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Last Week
    // Ensure Last Week Link Text is present


        boolean isDisplayed1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='block-2']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a")).isDisplayed();

        if (isDisplayed1) {
            System.out.print("   Test Case 2c Last Week Link Text Present");
        }else{
            System.out.print("   Test Case 2c Last Week Link Text not Present");
        }

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    // Last Month 
    // Ensure Last month link text present

        boolean isDisplayed2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='block-2']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/a")).isDisplayed();

        if (isDisplayed2) {
            System.out.print("   Test Case 2d Last Month Link Text Present");
        }else{
            System.out.print("   Test Case 2d Last Month Link Text not Present");
        }

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Year to Date
    // Ensure Year to Date Link Text is present

        boolean isDisplayed3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='block-2']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[5]/a")).isDisplayed();

        if (isDisplayed3) {
            System.out.print("   Test Case 2e Year to Date Link Text Present");
        }else{
            System.out.print("   Test Case 2e Last Year tp Date Link Text not Present");
        }

    Thread.sleep(3000);`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you are asking why some output is printed on new line, while other isn't.

That's because in some places you use

```
System.out.println
```

which prints a string and moves the cursor to new line. And sometimes you use

```
System.out.print
```

which prints a string and **does not** move the cursor to new line.

Comment: thank you so much for the clarification, appreciate it!